# Reduce Array of Objects with Percentage Calculation

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am working with an array of objects like:

```
const data = [
  {type: "Liberator", style: "Moderately Logical"},
  {type: "Protector", style: "Somewhat Passionate"},
  {type: "Energizer", style: "Balanced"},
  {type: "Observer", style: "Balanced"},
  {type: "Protector", style: "Balanced"},
  {type: "Liberator", style: "Moderately Logical"},
];
```

I am looking to reduce (I think) the array into a roll-up percentage breakdown of all items in the array.

For example, the top level "Protector" = 2 out of 6 or 33%. For each "Protector", there is 1 "Somewhat Passionate" out of 2 styles, the other being "Balanced" for 50%.

Expected Result:

```
const result = [
  {
    type: "Liberator",
    percent: "33%",
    [{
      style: "Moderately Logical",
      percent: "100%",
    }],
  },
  {
    type: "Protector",
    percent: "33%",
    [{
      style: "Somewhat Passionate",
      percent: "50%",
    },{
      style: "Balanced",
      percent: "50%",
    }],
  },
  {
    type: "Observer",
    percent: "17%",
    [{
      style: "Balanced",
      percent: "100%",
    }],
  },
  {
    type: "Energizer",
    percent: "17%",
    [{
      style: "Moderately Logical",
      percent: "100%",
    }],
  },
];
```

I have managed to get the original array the reduced with, but am now unsure of how to proceed with the calculations for each entry:

```
data.filter((d, index, self) =>
  index === self.findIndex(t => (
    t.type === d.type && t.style === d.style
  )),
);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by first calculating counts for each type and style, and then calculating their percentage:

```js
const data = [
  {type: "Liberator", style: "Moderately Logical"},
  {type: "Protector", style: "Somewhat Passionate"},
  {type: "Energizer", style: "Balanced"},
  {type: "Observer", style: "Balanced"},
  {type: "Protector", style: "Balanced"},
  {type: "Liberator", style: "Moderately Logical"},
];

function toPercent(arr) {
  const total = arr.reduce((a, c) => a + c.count, 0);
  return arr.map(({count, ...props}) => 
    ({ ...props, percent: Math.round((count * 100) / total) + '%'}));
}

const counts = data.reduce((a, c) => {
  a[c.type] = a[c.type] || {type: c.type, count: 0, styles: {}};
  a[c.type].count++;
  a[c.type].styles[c.style] = a[c.type].styles[c.style] || {style: c.style, count: 0};
  a[c.type].styles[c.style].count++;
  return a;
}, {});

const result = toPercent(Object.values(counts))
  .map(({styles, ...props}) => ({ ...props, styles: toPercent(Object.values(styles))}));
  
console.log(result);
```